# Strange VS2005 compile errors: unable to locate resource file (because the compiler keeps deleting it)

Tags: asp.net, ide, visual-studio-2005, compiler-errors

I AM GETTING THE FOLLOWING ERROR IN A VERY SIMPLE CLASS LIBRARY:

Error 1 Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\SMIT.SysAdmin.BusinessLayer.Resources.resources" to "obj\Debug\SMIT.SysAdmin.BusinessLayer.SMIT.SysAdmin.BusinessLayer.Resources.resources". Could not find file 'obj\Debug\SMIT.SysAdmin.BusinessLayer.Resources.resources'. SMIT.SysAdmin.BusinessLayer

Going to the Project Properties->Resource tab, I see that I defined do resources. Still, I tried to delete the resource file and recreate by going to the resource tab. When I recompile, I still get the same error.

Why is it even looking for a resource file? I define no resources on teh project properties tab and added no new resource file items.

Any suggestions of things to try?

## Update:

I found the missing file in an old backup. I copied it to the location where the compiler expected it, and then successfully recompiled the project that previously had compile time errors. However, when I rebuild the entire solution, it deletes the file that I previously restored and I'm back to where I started.

My solution contains several projects (maybe 10 or so). Could VS 2005 be having a problem determining dependencies and the proper order to compile these projects?

Comment: Surely VS2005 must be the stinker release of the decade. I can't believe all the issues that I have with it compared to other versions.

Comment: Velika, you prefer VS2003 and VS2002? Really?

Comment: Feature wise, 2005 is better. Bit is is slow and I have all sort of proj reference issue in 2005 that when, for example, when I upgrade to 2010, they go away. 2005 is slow and seems bug riddled. 2008 is much better on both counts. 2010 seems even better so far. 2003 and 2001 are too old and I would not go back, but I never had issues with any version like 2005.

Answer (score 0):

> Could VS 2005 be having a problem
>   determining dependencies and the
>   proper order to compile these
>   projects?

That sounds like it might be the reason why solution properties let you set the dependencies.  Visual Studio can obviously figure out that setup projects depend on other projects whose output they use, but if various projects don't have obvious dependencies then you should set them.